# VBA Renaming sheets based on varible in a for loop and storing new variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do the following tasks.

1. Create X-amount of new sheets in DestWorkbook based on row numbers in the Insert_Data_Sheet table. ***I've solved this***
2. Rename the sheet according to the D-Column data starting from "D2". So I would like to to rename the first sheet "1865727" and the second sheet "1872188" etc. ***I've solved this***
3. Store the data in D-column in a seperate variables. No luck with this yet

Here is pictures of the data:

https://pasteboard.co/HABwijq.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/HABwEhE.jpg

Full Code:

```
Public Sub TermSwap()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim DestWorkbook As Workbook, AC_Live_Workbook As Workbook, AC_Maturity_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Insert_Data_Sheet As Worksheet, AC_Live_Sheet As Worksheet, AC_Maturity_Sheet As Worksheet, Booked_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, d As Long, lastRowA_AC_Live As Long, lastRow_AC_Maturity As Long, NumberOfPages As Long
'Dim Swap_Link_Tid As Long


'I will use these in the end when importing the AC Reports
'AC_Live_Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "AVAA AC LIVE RAPORTTI")
'AC_Maturity_Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "AVAA AC MATURITY RAPORTTI")

'Insert filename from above lines as a parameter in the end
Set DestWorkbook = Workbooks("TermSwap")
Set AC_Live_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\z000479\Desktop\Makrot\Term Swap makro\Harjoitustiedostot\ALL_COLUMNS_FI_180817.xlsx")
Set AC_Maturity_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\z000479\Desktop\Makrot\Term Swap makro\Harjoitustiedostot\ALL_COLUMNS_FI_180820.xlsx")

Set Insert_Data_Sheet = DestWorkbook.Sheets("Insert_Data")
Set Booked_Sheet = DestWorkbook.Sheets("booked")
Set AC_Live_Sheet = AC_Live_Workbook.Sheets("Result")
Set AC_Maturity_Sheet = AC_Maturity_Workbook.Sheets("Result")

'Finds the last row in A-Column in the AC_Live_Sheet and AC_Maturity_Sheet
lastRow_AC_Live = AC_Live_Sheet.Cells(AC_Live_Sheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow_AC_Maturity = AC_Maturity_Sheet.Cells(AC_Maturity_Sheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


'Create X-amount of new sheets in DestWorkbook based on row numbers in the Insert_Data_Sheet table.SOLVED
' Rename the sheet according to the D-Column data starting from "D2". SOLVED
' Store the data in D-column in a seperate variables. UNSOLVED


NumberOfPages = Insert_Data_Sheet.Cells((Insert_Data_Sheet.Rows.Count), "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1



Dim target_range As String

For d = 2 To NumberOfPages + 1

    target_range = Insert_Data_Sheet.Range("D" & d).Value
    DestWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=DestWorkbook.Worksheets(DestWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)).Name = target_range
Next d




' AC LIVE Starts here:

' Show all cells
If AC_Live_Sheet.FilterMode Then
    AC_Live_Sheet.ShowAllData
End If

'Delete row 2
AC_Live_Sheet.Range("2:2").Delete


'Autofiter ON. Filters LIVE_DEAL and SWAP_LINK_TID. Change SWAP_LINK_TID to a variable.
'Range syntax here is Range ("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow)
If Not AC_Live_Sheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    AC_Live_Sheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    AC_Live_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow_AC_Live).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "LIVE_DEAL"
    AC_Live_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow_AC_Live).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
        "1889087"
End If

'Copy pastes visible cells to Booked_Sheet("A1")
With AC_Live_Sheet
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Booked_Sheet.Cells(1, 1)
End With


' AC_MATURITY starts here


' Show all cells
If AC_Maturity_Sheet.FilterMode Then
    AC_Maturity_Sheet.ShowAllData
End If

'Delete row 2
AC_Maturity_Sheet.Range("2:2").Delete


'Autofiter ON. Filters LIVE_DEAL and SWAP_LINK_TID.
'Range syntax here is Range ("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow)
'I need to change SWAP_LINK_TID to a variable
If Not AC_Maturity_Sheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    AC_Maturity_Sheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    AC_Maturity_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow_AC_Maturity).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "LIVE_DEAL", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=MAT_DEAL"
    AC_Maturity_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow_AC_Maturity).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
        "1889087"

End If

'Copy pastes visible cells to Booked_Sheet("A1")
With AC_Maturity_Sheet
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Booked_Sheet.Cells(6, 1)
End With


'Closes AC Workbooks and activates the Booked_Sheet
' Error here. It asked the file to be saved. I want to ignore it.
AC_Live_Workbook.Close
AC_Maturity_Workbook.Close
Booked_Sheet.Activate


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: AC_Live_Workbook.Close False  to not have the save changes prompt. You will lose any changes made.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about "Store the data in D-column in a seperate variables. No luck with this yet" ? Are this data not numbers are these numbers the same as the new sheet names?

Comment: The data is numbers and the data is the same as the new sheet names. Maybe I could include the filters in this for loop so I could use the target variable?

Comment: What are you doing with these numbers that you need them in variables?

Comment: Are you applying them one at a time as a filter or should they all be applied in one go?

Comment: One at a time. Like this

        AC_Live_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow_AC_Live).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
            target_range

Answer (score 0):

The following is to show how you might load the unique column D numbers into a dictionary as its keys and loop that dictionary's keys to add your new sheets. You could do your filter in the same loop, again using the current key of the dictionary for filtering or use it later. This is not intended to be copy-paste-work but to show you the parts you could use.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
   Dim valuesDict As Object, arr(), i As Long, lastRow As Long
   Set valuesDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row  'find last row of your numbers

      Select Case lastRow
      Case Is < 2
          Exit Sub
      Case 2   '< Load your number into an array
          ReDim arr(1, 1)
          arr(1, 1) = .Range("D2")
      Case Else
          arr = .Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Value
      End Select
   End With
   For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) 'Add unique values to the range
       valuesDict(arr(i, 1)) = 1
   Next

   Dim key As Variant
   For Each key In valuesDict.keys
       If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & key & "'!A1)") Then  'If sheet doesn't exist add it. Credit to @Rory for this method.
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
           ActiveSheet.NAME = key
       End If
   Next key
   'Other code.......
   For Each key In valuesDict.keys
       AC_Live_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$DS$" & lastRow_AC_Live).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=key
   Next key
   'Other code
End Sub
```

Comment: I think lists or dictionarys are great way to solve this. However i don't have much experience in this with VBA and I'm having trouble understanding the code

Comment: Can't access. Work comp

Comment: Ask your questions here then. At some point the thread will be moved if it gets too long though.

Comment: What would be the first steps to integrate this code into my code. I could change the workbooks and worksheets at least. I'll try to make the changes I feel I should do and edit my answer